# arbitrary type which could be unrelated, but types are related

Tags: typescript, generics

In this sample code:

```
function test<T>(param: T & {id: number}): T {
    const {id, ...rest} = param;
    return rest;
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCoD4AUADgIYBOxAtgFyLaIBkiA3jACY1ggUBGKpAvgEoadJgFgAUImmIICDMzYAaRADp1pdFH6IAvIhLkKAbkkzEmqCFJJNGUxP6SgA)

Typescript says that:

> Type `Omit<T & { id: number; }, "id">` is not assignable to type `T`.
>
> `T` could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to `Omit<T & { id: number; }, "id">`.(2322)

Wouldn't `T` and `Omit<T & {id: number}, "id">` *exactly the same type*?

Maybe it's because we don't enforce that `T` holds an object:

```
function test<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(param: T & {id: number}): T {
    const {id, ...rest} = param;
    return rest;
}
```

[that doesn't work either](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EAlFCOAJ2MwxpjAHMAaRcAazDgHcwAPkEAKAA4BDGhIC2ALkS4AZIgDeMYgrAgZAIxQ0AvgEoFuVQFgAUIluJqYDGo0cAdO5roohxAF5EktIyANzWdoieUCA0SJ4YoVaG1kA). The error is now:

> Type `Omit<T & { id: number; }, "id">` is not assignable to type `T`.
>
> `Omit<T & { id: number; }, "id">` is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'.(2322)

I guess there's a case in which that wouldn't hold, if `T` did in fact had a field `id`. I've tried that too, but I couldn't find how to express to the compiler that constraint, that `T` cannot have an `id` field.

Can I type this function I'm trying to define, or somehow convince (without casts) typescript that this is correct? Obviously it would work i I started from `T` and returned `Omit<T, 'id'>`.. but I'm trying to type a more complex generic function which actually works on a type `T` but also receives items of type `T & {id: number}`.

Comment: What if you force T to have the id ? `function test<T extends { id: string }>(param: T):  Omit<T, "id"> { ...`

Comment: but the point is that `T` does NOT have the `id`. It doesn't have the id, but for the purpose of the generic function i'm trying to type, together with `T` I'm receiving also an `id` field that I need, but then must strip from the object to obtain a `T`

Comment: Generally speaking the compiler's not great at arbitrary generic type manipulation, so there are definitely cases where you have two equivalent types the compiler can't see as equivalent.  But that's not the case here; `T` may have an `id` property, and you're claiming that the output is still a `T` even with the `id` property removed, which can lead to runtime errors like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBRQ4N).  Since what you're doing is not type safe, there's not really a way to do it without the moral equivalent of type assertions (what you're calling "casts").  See the other q/a for more info.

Comment: @jcalz yes I mentionned in my question "I couldn't find how to express to the compiler that constraint, that T cannot have an id field.". I tried `& {id?: never}` but that didn't do the trick. So it would be more that TS doesn't allow to express that or doesn't take it into account...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to type a more complex generic function which actually works on a type `T` but also receives items of type `T & {id: number}`

Would this suffice?

```
type WithID = { id: string; }

function test<T extends Partial<WithID>>(param: T): Omit<T, 'id'> {
    const {id, ...rest} = param;
    return rest;
}

const a = test({});
const b = test({ id: 'foo' });
const c = test({ id: 'foo', num: 42 });
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdWgWwA4HsBOAXB8BWBXWbAMw1ABMBTRVUZfdNWSgWACgk0tQBvUAMQA2AQ2wBfUMXSpEoAOQABVIOjCAdsEwBPZJVgBjdNGSYAtJEqDd6WHIDc7dtt2gA6tEyQAkgBFQAXl4EcgAuUCIjNQBzO1AxRzZifDV9TGhUNVBMPUwAHnBQSgAPbLVyeAAFYSxVQVz3T18APiaACmRq4UQw8ABKMIB5RA98gBp5aHI5Jt52UHnQfQyiXknxgDpN9ByJQI70Loc2BdBtzAZM7aIj+LZ2JbUV4QCsnNaeMV6j50pQAEEXkJRLkfqhiKBhE0jvdltgAEYvbJEd7BMJyUioORxL5OHS-ABCgJEeVB4LhUISDxW+kRbz4kzRGLk4zU+G6oAALAAmbHfPGgADCROBpMWFLYQA)

Comment: for my purpose, not really, that's what I get out of the box with the destructuring (Omit<T, 'id'>). Basically my problem, the way that I'm trying to solve my issue, is that I would like TS to unify `Omit<T & {id:number}, 'id'>` and `T`, and it doesn't want to. Possibly the answer is "you're expecting too much from the compiler".

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery I don't follow. You want a type union like this `Omit<T & {id:number}, 'id'> | T`?

Comment: but the types should be the same (minus the concern that T shouldn't have an id field), so why would i want an union. My point was that T+id-id should be the same as T (if T didn't have an id field initially)